# How to prevent edge cases or delay for a deadline of a scheduled task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, cron, scheduled-tasks

Suppose I have an event scheduled in the future with `start_date`, `end_date` (inclusive), `timezone`, and `status`. The dates are wall-time since users are from all of the places with different timezones. There will be incoming transactions and I'd like to check the validity of these transactions against the status of the task.

If the status of the task is `active` then it's still valid. What I'm planning to do is to setup a cron job (or ActiveJob in Rails) to run every 15 minutes to check whether the task has already started or ended according to the user's `timezone` setting and update the `status` field.

The problem is that suppose the task's `end_date` is 15 December and the cron job begins at exactly 16 December 00:00 at which the task should be already expired and the cron job takes approximately 2 minutes to complete the whole database. Then the `status` will updated to `inactive` at 16 around December 00:02. If there is a transaction coming in at 16 December 00:01 and then the application checks the validity against its `status` which is still `active` but in fact it's already past the deadline.

Any ideas how to combat this problem?

By the way, although the application itself is not really serious and can afford some mismatches, I'm still worried about the data intregrity when querying since there will be some datapoints missing out of the valid date range.

Answer (score 0):

Cron won't work since it creates the problem you describe, but with activejob you can tell it the exact date and time to run https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

By the way, if something depends on a date, why don't you actually check that date instead of the "status" column?

Comment: Good point about checking the date itself. I have thought about the idea as well but I'm worried about one thing. The `status` is also showing at the frontend and the polling rate at the frontend is 5 min. Then it can be a delay between the updated status and what the user can see from the frontend. Otherwise I need to update the frontend every minute but not sure whether that's a good idea since it might put too much work on the server.

Comment: Also, regarding activejob, even you can tell the exact time and date it sill takes some time to execute the command for the whole database. Isn't that still a concern?

Comment: If you have the exact date and time when the status should change then you don't need to ask the server every 5 minuts if it changed, you can use javascript to change the status at that exact time using setTimeout with some math to change the status instantly instead of asking the server. You can have that polling too though, but you don't have to wait since you already know the date and time.

Comment: updating the database shouldn't be a problem, you can have a single query to update everything and with proper indexes it would take miliseconds, but you don't even need to process the whole database, you can create an activejob to update just a single record

Comment: If you still want to change that status value, I would do a combination of cron and activejob. Check every 15 minutes the record that should be updated over the next 15/20 minutes and then add an activejob for each of them with the exact date. That way you don't have all the activejobs waiting for thing that maybe are far on the future, only the next-to-finish ones.

Comment: Good idea about the javascript to update the status. Also the solution with cron and activejob combition seems to make sense albeit a bit complex. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: What's your thoughts about checking the date or status? What would be the best practice in your opinion?

Comment: Personally, with only this information, I'll check/query using the column with the date, but I don't know all your requirements, maybe in your actual case is better to check the status column. As always, it depends.

Comment: I was thinking sort of the same as well that checking the date would be more straight forward. I was just worried about the information discrepancy between back- and frontend but since you mentioned about checking the deadline by JavaScript as well. I think that could be a good way to go.

Comment: Also, each time checking the validity of a transaction you have to recalculate the time (wall time). That might not be the most efficient. However, checking against status doesn't require recalculating time since it's already done updating the status.